# How to get the uncovered parts of code in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

I wrote a simple reducer :

```
const simpleCounterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT_COUNT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT_COUNT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default simpleCounterReducer;
```

And then a few simple tests to cover all the possible options.

```
import simpleCounterReducer from '../src/reducers/simple-counter.js';

describe('counter works and', () => {
    test('can handle increments', () => {
        expect(
            simpleCounterReducer(0, {
                type: 'INCREMENT_COUNT'
            })
        ).toBe(1);
    });

    test('can handle decrements', () => {
        expect(
            simpleCounterReducer(1, {
                type: 'DECREMENT_COUNT'
            })
        ).toBe(0);
    });

    test('can handle invalid actions', () => {
        expect(
            simpleCounterReducer(4, {
                type: 'SOME_RANDOM_ACTION'
            })
        ).toBe(4);
    });
});
```

Then I ran this command : `npx jest --colors --coverage`

But even though I have covered all parts of the code, I am getting an uncovered line. Is it something wrong with jest or am I missing something. And is there a way to find out in jest, the parts of code that are not covered.

[Image for jest test coverage output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oytTg.png)

Comment: Show your report

Comment: You're using a default value (`state = 0`) but none of your tests exercise the default value. This is likely a branch coverage issue rather than line coverage.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger You are right, adding a test and passing state as undefined worked. But, is there a way to get uncovered lines, cause i found nothing in jest docs

Comment: If you have 100% coverage there should be no "uncovered lines". If you do not have 100% statement, branch, and function coverage on a line it probably marks that line as uncovered (I'm assuming here since I do not know exactly what is being marked as uncovered).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to see the lines that are not covered you can open in a browser the generated report.

By default the report is here `./coverage/lcov-report/index.html`.

But you also see in the console the line numbers of the uncovered lines (it is not the number of lines that are not cover but the line numbers, and in your case it is the first line).

Also some config for the coverage if needed : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean

Side note, it uses istanbul behind the scene : https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul

Comment: Also for others who are interested if there is a function that is uncovered that you want to skip over, you can pass a comment just before the function /* istanbul ignore next */